# GridDB Unable to Perform Search on Partitioned Collection

Tags: griddb

I have collected and stored a huge dataset on the sales of motorcycle parts' shops in different cities. Since GridDB is known for its high-speed query results, it is a strong candidate for data storage.

I wanted to create a partitioned collection of data based on its cities to pinpoint those locations in order to maintain the high availability of parts. The partitioned collection created is shown below:

```
CREATE COLLECTION Bike_Parts_Sales (
    id INTEGER,
    city TEXT,
    amount DOUBLE,
    item TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    TYPE='PARTITION',
    COLUMN='city',
    INTERVAL='100'
);
```

I performed a simple `SELECT` query on the column `region` between a specific date as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Bike_Parts_Sales WHERE region = 'KHI' AND timestamp between '2024-03-25' and '2024-03-29';
```

However, GridDB was unable to perform the query and returned back with the following error:

```
ERROR: Query execution failed: [GS_ERR_PARTIAL_SEARCH_INCOMPLETE] Query execution failed due to an incomplete search in the partitioning order. Please retry the query later.
```

The partitioning error usually occurs when the partitioning column is not used in the query to fetch the data. However, I have queried on the partitioned column. In addition, I have retried the query on multiple occasions and at different intervals of time and even executed the query on a single date, but it has not solved the issue.

```
SELECT * FROM Bike_Parts_Sales WHERE region = 'KHI' AND timestamp = '2024-03-25';
```

As far as I have diagnosed, the issue is because GridDB is unable to perform a search on all the partitions. What is its root cause?

Kindly assist, and thank you in advance.